# Panel Regression in Pandas issue

Tags: python, pandas, regression

I'm using the [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24074481/fama-macbeth-regression-in-python-pandas-or-statsmodels) to run a panel regression in python, as I do not have access to `statsmodels`

My dataframe looks as follows:

```
                                                                                                       Sum Amt_1         ...                   Sum Amt_2
Date      Range_1    Range_2    info_1    info_2       info_3                   info_4                     ...                              
01/01/19   &gt;720  &gt;30.0    &gt;5.0    &lt;=70.0   lessthan_12m              &lt;= 0                    0.00         ...                     631427.36
                                                                                  1-10                       0.00         ...                      30420.78
                                                                                  21-30                      0.00         ...                      20276.26
                                                                                  31-40                      0.00         ...                      76939.48
                                                         morethan_12m           &gt; 50                    0.00         ...                      10288.87
```

The answerers dataframe looks like this:

```
            Intercept      beta     r12to2   r36to13
caldt                                               
1963-07-01  -1.497012 -0.765721   4.379128 -1.918083
1963-08-01  11.144169 -6.506291   5.961584 -2.598048
1963-09-01  -2.330966 -0.741550  10.508617 -4.377293
1963-10-01   0.441941  1.127567   5.478114 -2.057173
1963-11-01   3.380485 -4.792643   3.660940 -1.210426
```

I try to run the same regression using the code below, where I effectively want to do the same thing that was done in the answer but by grouping across all columns except `Sum Amt_1` and `Sum Amt_2`, as these are all categorical variables.

```
def ols_coef(x,formula):

    return ols(formula,data=x).fit().params

gamma = (df.groupby(['Date', 'Range_1', 'Range_2', 'info_1', 'info_2']))

                .apply(ols_coef,'Sum_Amt_1 ~ C(Range_1)  + C(Range_2) + C(info_1) + C(info_2)'))
```

However, when I run  `print(gamma)` I get:

```
                                                                                     Intercept
Date      Range_1           Range_2        info_1             info_2                                 
01/01/19   &gt; 30.0         &gt; 5.0     DQ_lessthan_12m     &gt; 50               1994.545600
                                                              &lt;= 0                  0.000000
                                                              1-10                     0.000000
                                                              11-20                    0.000000
                                                              21-30                 5740.748889
                                                              31-40                    0.000000
                                                              41-50                    0.000000
```

I understand that the regression is only run on non-indexed elements, but how do I run the regression on these indexed elements, that is `'Range_1', 'Range_2', 'info_1', 'info_2'` on `Sum_Amt_1`?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot groupby named indexes in pandas by calling their names. When you run `df.groupby(['Date', 'Range_1', 'Range_2', 'info_1', 'info_2'])` it is effectively doing nothing. Here an example of what I mean:

```
### Creating a multi-index dataframe
arrays = [['bar', 'bar', 'baz', 'baz', 'foo', 'foo', 'qux', 'qux'],['one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two']]

tuples = list(zip(*arrays))

index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples, names=['first', 'second'])

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(6, 6), index=index[:6], columns=index[:6])

df.columns = [' '.join(col).strip() for col in df.columns]

### grouping by named index

df.groupby(['first', 'second']).sum() ##Nothing happens
df.groupby(level = 0).sum()  ## Correct way to groupby index
```

I would suggest that if you want to run a regression on indexed variables, either you reindex your dataframe by simply `df.reset_index`(then you can call names), or you call the levels explicitly. The choice is yours.

More info can be found in this post here: [Pandas group by index and calculate sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46229807/pandas-group-by-index-and-calculate-sum)