# Merge Column Values by Index

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, merge

I want to merge the values from the dummy variables on the columns by the index.

Here is an example:

```
data = {'Values': [0, 1, 0, 0], 'Values2': [1, 1, 0, 1],'Values3': [0, 0, 0, 1]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data,index =['position1', 'position2', 'position1', 'position2'])

print(df)

Output:
    Values  Values2 Values3
position1   0   1   0
position2   1   1   0
position1   0   0   0
position2   0   1   1
```

The result final result I wish to have. How can i do this? pivot tables?

```
    Values  Values2 Values3
position1   0   1   0
position2   1   2   1
```

Comment: `df.sum(level=0)`?

Comment: [Groupby sum](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html) -> `df.groupby(level=0).sum()` Note: sum with level argument will give `FutureWarning`.

Comment: Is there a better dupe target than [Pandas group by index and calculate sum](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46229807/15497888)?

Comment: we can always add others if needed ;)

Comment: Sounds good. I'm just going to make that answer better.

Comment: thanks guys! thats it.

Comment: The duplicate should be better now.